# Positioning NavBar at Top of Page but Losing Clickability on Main Content

Tags: css

I have a page where I want the navbar to always appear at the top of the page as I scroll the content. I was able to accomplish this by adding using the following CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-main {
    width: 97%;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    min-height: 75vh; /* will cover the 75% of viewport */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 125px; /*height of your footer*/
    margin-top: 30px;
    z-index:-1
}
```

The problem is that once I added the `z-index:-1` the main content lost the ability to be clicked. Without the `z-index:-1` then the content of the main container scrolls on top of the navbar and not behind it. What do i need to do to keep the navbar at the top, scroll the content under the navbar, and keep the ability to click the items in the main container?  Here is a simplified version of the _layout page where this all resides:

```
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="edadTopNavigation">
    <div class="container-fluid app-navbar">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse app-navbar-text-section">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="adminDropdownMenuLink" href='#' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><div class="fa fa-cog"></div> Admin</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="adminDropdownMenuLink">
                        <div>
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Acronym" asp-action="Index">Acronyms</a>
                        </div>                      
                        <div>
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Users</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
    <div class="container-main">
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer style="position:relative;top:0">
        <div>
        </div>
    </footer>}
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just give the navbar a z-index of 2 and the main content a z-index of 1?

Comment: try adding `z-index: 2` to your navbar and then `z-index: 1` to your main content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make a simple sandbox of this situation and I coded the nav-bar like this:

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: fff; /* For testing */
background-color: #333; /* For testing*/
padding: 1rem; /* For testing*/
z-index: 100;
}
```

and made a simple container with a main element inside and added a bunch of links and paragraphs in it to test if I can click on links & select the paragraphs or not. 
The styling of the container:

```
.container {
background-color: orangered; /* For testing*/
max-width: 1200px;
height: 700vh; /* To make the container super long to test clickability it */
margin: 5rem auto; /* To center the container */
z-index: -50;
}
```

and it seems to work just fine, try to make sure that your nav-bar height doesn't fill the 100% of your viewport height and tinker a bit with the styling like add

> left: 0;

in the nav-bar styling to see if it will work.

Comment: This worked except 1. I had to use a non - z-index on the container. 2. The navBar menu has a dropdown. Now when that menu item is clicked, the dropdown is hidden by the main container. I modified the code above

Answer (score 1):

Just use a higher z-index for navbar. And the main container isn't scrolling on top of navbar. Your code is fine but, you need to push the main element a little below navbar. Take a look at this code:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container-main {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  min-height: 75vh;
  /* will cover the 75% of viewport */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 125px;
  /*height of your footer*/
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="edadTopNavigation">
      <div class="container-fluid app-navbar">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container-main">
    <main role="main">
      @RenderBody()
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer style="position:relative;top:0">
    <div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works except now I have another issue. The navBar menu has a dropdown. Now when that menu item is clicked, the dropdown is hidden by the main container. I modified the code above