# Prevent NavBar from Expanding When Using Z-Index

Tags: css

I posted a previous question concerning [Positioning NavBar at Top of Page but Losing Clickability on Main Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860232/positioning-navbar-at-top-of-page-but-losing-clickability-on-main-content/64860753#64860753). The question was answered but it has now led to an unintended consequence. At first it prevented a dropdown menu item from appearing above the content. I updated the dropdown with a `z-index: 99999; position: relative;` value to get it to display above the content but now it expands the height of the Header section. Here are 3 images.

Unselected Dropdown:

[image: UnSelected Dropdown]

How it used to appear:

[image: How it used to appear]

How it now appears using `z-index: 99999;position: relative;`

[image]

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="edadTopNavigation">
        <div class="container-fluid app-navbar">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse app-navbar-text-section">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="adminDropdownMenuLink" href='#' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><div class="fa fa-cog"></div> Admin</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="adminDropdownMenuLink">
                            <div>
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Acronym" asp-action="Index">Acronyms</a>
                            </div>                      
                            <div>
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Users</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">States</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Countries</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the current CSS:

```
.navbar {
    /* margin-bottom: 0px;*/
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 200
}
    
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fffff2;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
}
```

What can I do to get the dropdown to display like image 2 instead of image 3?

Comment: you need to use absolute positioning on your dropdown (or remove the relative positioning if it used to work)

Comment: @Pete  If I use Absolute (or remove Relative) the menu does not appear above the main container.